# PHP: Why am I getting an encapsulated string error with my "scandir" call?

Tags: php, string, error-handling, scandir

The following line returns the error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"/"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\TRS_News\TRS-Home.php on line 29".

```
$artProps=scandir("Articles/".date("y-m-d")."/".$instancesFiles.""); /*This is the troublesome line*/
```

Comment: What is in $instancesFiles? I cannot get that error and I've tried a few things to break it. What are the lines above that might be causing this. Sounds like there is an issue above.

Comment: Aside: You may want to refactor to use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` global constant instead of hardcoding '/' to make your code platform agnostic.